# Javascript: export/import a constant is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I have a file with mocks and export constants from that files to my views(which are react components). But these constants are undefined. For example in my `ListMock.js` I have the following:

```
export const MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST = {
    list1: {
        id: 1,
        filtersTags: [
            {
                filterTagName: "filter1",
                filteredItemsCount: 9
            },
            {
                filterTagName: "filter2",
                filteredItemsCount: 5
            }
        ]

    } 

    ...
};
```

And import this constant here:

```
...
import {MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST} from '../../../mocks/ListMock';

export class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
        const {listItemIndex} = this.props;

        return (
            <li className={`panel ${styles.listItem} ${styles.listPanel}`}>
                ...
                <ExpandedListItem listItemIndex={listItemIndex}
                     expandedListItem={MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST[`list${listItemIndex}`]} />
            </li>);

    }
}
```

Here I get an error, as the `MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST` is `undefined`. But if I change the binding to this:

```
 return (
            <li className={`panel ${styles.listItem} ${styles.listPanel}`}>
                ...
                <ExpandedListItem listItemIndex={listItemIndex}
                      expandedListItem={MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST} />
            </li>);

    }
```

in my `ExpandedListItem` component `expandedListItem` prop which was bound to `MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST` constant, is defined.

Which is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What is the value of `listItemIndex`?

Comment: It can be **1** for example.

Comment: And what happens if you `console.log(MOCKED_EXPANDED_LIST[\`list${listItemIndex}\`]);` outside of the JSX template?

Comment: Ooo! Object is accessible.

Comment: My guess would be that something is wrong with `listItemIndex`.

Comment: Check your `listItemIndex` values. Be aware that array indexes usually start from 0, but you have list started from `list1`

Comment: Hey Anoush, how did you circumvent this problem eventually?

Comment: @Fluous this is the debugger issue, if you console.log that variables, you'll see imported values. Of course, if imports are made correctly. So if that doesn't work for you, maybe there is a need to check the imports. Because as I remember, `undefined` was  while debugging. And maybe further I found an issue in my code. Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly what happened.